# I try to remove a value and set a value in this Firestore Transaction but not working

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

I try to remove a value from an array but can only find examples of this where the `index` of the value is first obtained and then the value is removed using `splice`.

I don't have the index, the array is just this:

[image]

I must remove the `ANONYMOUS`and add `NON_ANONYMOUS`

`const userRef = firebase.db.collection('users').doc(userId);`

```
    firebase.db
        .runTransaction(transaction => {
            // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
            return transaction.get(userRef).then(doc => {
                if (!doc.exists) {
                    console.log('Transaction failed: User dont exist!');
                    return;
                }

                const newRoles = doc.data().roles;
                newRoles.push(ROLES.NON_ANON);
                // HERE I MUST REMOVE THE ROLE ANONYMOUS 
                transaction.update(userRef, { roles: newRoles });
            });
        })
        .then(function (newRoles) {
            console.log(`Transaction successfully committed! ${newRoles}`);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Transaction failed: ', error);
        });
```

I have tried like this

```
const newRoles= newRoles.splice(newRoles .indexOf('anonymouse'), 1);
```

but it does not work. What is it I've done wrong?

Comment: This is userRef: `const userRef = firebase.db.collection('users').doc(userId);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are case sensitive in JavaScript.  Your code is looking for "anonymouse" but the array contains "ANONYMOUS".  You must pass the exact string to remove.  I suggest logging the final value of teh array before you update it in order to make sure you actually removed it.